# ROOT style plotting in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: root style plot]

I would like to plot in this style. I have seen people using this type of plot in ROOT(CERN) but i would like to do in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A lttile more info other than figure would be helpful. Such as what library are used.